# How to use functions from different classes in Action Script 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have 2 classes, named `Class1` and `Class2`.

How would I use a function from `Class1`, in `Class2`?

Comment: More code would be helpful, are you simply trying to learn AS3? You probably want to have `Class2` extend `Class1`, but I'd have to understand more about what they actually do.

Comment: Lol! Dude learn some OOP! But I guess you need to know what OOP is first :)))))

Answer (score 2):

To access a function from a class you need to create an instance of it via the `new` keyword (unless the function is `static`). This instance could be created *within* Class2:

```
public class Class2
{

    // The property holding your instance is defined here so you can access
    // it within any method of this class, as this is defined at class-level
    // rather than within a function (like the constructor).
    private var class1:Class1;


    /**
     * Class2's constructor.
     * (Called automatically when an instance of Class2 is created).
     */
    public function Class2()
    {
        // Create an instance of Class1 and assign it to the class-level
        // property "class1" (defined above).
        class1 = new Class1();

        // You can call methods of Class1 now, via class1.
        class1.someMethod();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are lots of different ways to do this.

Call a method directly on a class

Class1

```
class Class1{
     public function Class1(){
          var class2:Class2 = new Class2(); //create a new Class2 object
          class2.CallMe(); //call the CallMe function on Class2, note the . to indicate CallMe is a property of Class2
     }

 }
```

Class2

```
class Class2{
     public function Class2(){ //class 2 constructor. This is always called when you create a new Object()

     }

     public function CallMe():void{ //note this function is public
         trace("I'm class 2");
     }

 }
```

Pass a ref to a function from another class

Class1

```
class Class1{
     public function Class1(){
          var class2:Class2 = new Class2(this.CallBack); //create a new Class2 object
          //note I didn't add () to the end of CallBack, I just used the function name
     }

    private function CallBack(aString:String):void{ //note we can use private here
         trace(aString) //I'm from Class2
  }

 }
```

Class2

```
class Class2{
     public function Class2(aFunction:Function){ //class 2 constructor. Here we an accept the function
          aFunction("I'm from Class2"); //note I can pass a string back to class1
     }

 }
```

You can also extend classes and call methods on the super class

Class1

```
class Class1 extends Class2{
     public function Class1(){
        super.CallFromClass(); //I'm super
     }

 }
```

Class2

```
class Class2{
     public function Class1(){

     }

    public function CallFromClass():void{
        trace("I'm super");
   }

 }
```

Take a look at this link for further reading:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/oop_as3.html

Answer (score 0):

```
// Main.as
package {

    public class Main() {
        public function Main() {
        }

        public function hello():void {
            trace("Hello from class Main"):
        }
    }
}

//Hi.as
package {
    public class Hi() {

        private var _main:Main;

        public function Hi() {
        }

        public function fromMain():void {
            _main = new Main();    //initialize an object of class Main()
            _main.hello();    //call methods
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `function/property` of `Class2` from `Class1`, if that `function/property` is 'visible' for `Class1`. Access to properties/methods of class is controlled by specific attribute,which can have these values: `internal (default),private,public,protected,...` Check [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f32.html).

Then if it is 'visible', all you need,is to have reference to class(to access `static` properties/methods) or to instance of class(to access `non-static` properties/methods).